# Assign a class other than .sticky for sticky posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

WordPress automatically adds a class called `.sticky` to posts that are marked as a sticky post. The front-end framework Foundation uses a `.sticky` class to make items stick to the page which presents an obvious conflict.

The ideal solution would be to modify the WordPress class. Is it possible to change the class that WordPress assigns to sticky posts to something other than `.sticky`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please and include it in your functions.php

```
function change_sticky_class($classes) {
  if (in_array('sticky', $classes, true)) {
    $classes = array_diff($classes, array("sticky"));
    $classes[] = 'wp-sticky';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class','change_sticky_class');
```